# Zero gl_VertexID for every vertex when redrawn from event handler in Firefox

Tags: firefox, safari, webgl, webgl2

I use `gl_VertexID` for texture selection (passing it in a variable from vertex to fragment shader), and this approach works well for first `drawElements()`. But when I redraw frames on `mousemove` event my shader gets zero `gl_VertexID` for every vertex in Firefox (on Chrome it works perfectly).

**UPDATE**: I attach the code of my shaders:

vertex.glsl:

```c
#version 300 es

precision mediump float;

in vec2 texture;
in vec3 position;

out vec2 vert_texture;
flat out int vert_vertex_id;

uniform mat4 projection;
uniform mat4 view;

void main() {
    vert_texture = texture;
    vert_vertex_id = gl_VertexID;
    gl_Position = projection * view * vec4(position, 1.0);
}
```

fragment.glsl

```c
#version 300 es

precision mediump float;

in vec2 vert_texture;
flat in int vert_vertex_id;

out vec4 frag_color;

uniform int texture_index[MAX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS];
uniform sampler2D textures[MAX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS];

vec4 get_texture_color(int index, vec2 point) {
    switch (index) {
        case 0: return texture(textures[0], point);
        case 1: return texture(textures[1], point);
        case 2: return texture(textures[2], point);
        case 3: return texture(textures[3], point);
        case 4: return texture(textures[4], point);
        case 5: return texture(textures[5], point);
        case 6: return texture(textures[6], point);
        case 7: return texture(textures[7], point);
#if MAX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS >= 16
        case 8: return texture(textures[8], point);
        case 9: return texture(textures[9], point);
        case 10: return texture(textures[10], point);
        case 11: return texture(textures[11], point);
        case 12: return texture(textures[12], point);
        case 13: return texture(textures[13], point);
        case 14: return texture(textures[14], point);
        case 15: return texture(textures[15], point);
#endif
#if MAX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS >= 32
        case 16: return texture(textures[16], point);
        case 17: return texture(textures[17], point);
        case 18: return texture(textures[18], point);
        case 19: return texture(textures[19], point);
        case 20: return texture(textures[20], point);
        case 21: return texture(textures[21], point);
        case 22: return texture(textures[22], point);
        case 23: return texture(textures[23], point);
        case 24: return texture(textures[24], point);
        case 25: return texture(textures[25], point);
        case 26: return texture(textures[26], point);
        case 27: return texture(textures[27], point);
        case 28: return texture(textures[28], point);
        case 29: return texture(textures[29], point);
        case 30: return texture(textures[30], point);
        case 31: return texture(textures[31], point);
#endif
    }
}

void main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS; ++i) {
        if (vert_vertex_id < texture_index[i]) {
            frag_color = get_texture_color(i, vert_texture);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Here I use `gl_VertexID` passed from the vertex shader to determine a number of texture by accessing `texture_index`.

**UPDATE 2**: I found the same behaviour on Safari (after enabling WebGL2), so I can assume this is not a Firefox bug.

Comment: I am using firefox 68 on macos 10.12 and just implemented a gl_VertexID based drawArrays vertex shader yesterday, and it is working here, although I am not passing it onwards to the fragment shader.  Also I am animating via requestAnimationFrame.  Have you any code to share?

Comment: So I just tried passing gl_VertexID over to my fragment shader.  Since this is not a 1:1 relationship, the int is passed 'flat', but then this seems to be subject to 'ProvokingVertex' rules, which although not exposed on the WebGL2 API, it seem to me to be implemented as the last vertex of each triangle.  Maybe you know this already, but I learned something :)

Comment: @Peter I have shared the shaders code.

Comment: Well it seems you are way ahead of me with this stuff.  I have not tried the new texture array stuff so far.  It looks like you are rendering GL_POINTS, so the 'provoking vertex' should not be an issue.  The (vert_vertex_id < texture_index[i]) looks odd, I somehow expected an '==' there.  Just an observation, and not related to the actual problem.  Maybe try switching the render loop to RAF, since that seems to work here.  I am using tinygo/Wasm, but happy to share some code if needed.  Only other suggestion would be firefox has a setting for hardware acceleration.  Sorry I wasn't more help.